# Does QML supports type conversion by 'as' keyword?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have such line in my qml file:

```
var someName = index as String;
```

Qml shows error

> Expected token `;'

on this line. Does it mean that qml does not support 'as' keyword? Or maybe there is other reason of this problem?

Comment: Where did you get that `as` is a QML keyword ?, which I know is only used in imports to establish aliases. What do you expect when executing`index as String;`?

Comment: `as` keyword is typescript as I know, not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. In Qt 5.15 and 6, QML supports "as-casting" operator as an extension to an otherwise compliant ECMAScript syntax/grammar parser. However, it is barely documented at the moment.

You can use it to give engine and tools a type-hint, so they could compile (JIT) into faster native code, or generate more sensible lints.

Note that JavaScript types like "String", "Array" or "Date" are not supported. It won't even work on `list<>` types (yet). You can only cast to registered QML types, subclasses of `QObject`, and starting with Qt 6.6 (coming out September 2023) primitives — named registered `Q_GADGET` types — will also be supported. If value type is not compatible, `as` cast expression evaluates to `null`.

For example:

*[qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qqmllanguage/data/jittedAsCast.qml](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/2426b622e1852a418e97a3be89ea1b3eb18b8fb9/tests/auto/qml/qqmllanguage/data/jittedAsCast.qml)*:

```
import QtQml

QtObject {
    property QtObject obj: Timer {
        interval: 1
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (++interval === 10)
                running = false
        }
    }
    property bool running: (obj as Timer).running
    property int interval: (obj as Timer).interval
}
```

*[qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qqmllanguage/data/asValueType.qml](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/cae23efe45ee92b41b7899a28d4d1d7d1048584d/tests/auto/qml/qqmllanguage/data/asValueType.qml):*

```
pragma ValueTypeBehavior: Addressable
import QtQml
import StaticTest

QtObject {
    property var a
    property rect b: a as rect
    property bool c: a instanceof rect
    property bool d: ({x: 10, y: 20}) instanceof point
    property var e: ({x: 10, y: 20}) as point
    property var f: "red" as withString
}
```

See also:

- https://github.com/SublimeText/QML/issues/17

Comment: it seems currently qml script compiler has some issues with types/casts/marshalling between custom/c++ components and other native methods. writing (item as Item) prevents some TypeErrors in our case

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.  To ensure a string type in the given example you'd create a `String` JS object explicitly.

`var someName = new String(index);`

EDIT: added `new`, see comments.  :)

Comment: Shouln't you add a `new` if you create a JS object? If I remember right, the `this`-Pointer in the Object will not be set correctly otherwise. Or is it something different with Strings?

Comment: @derM Not sure about `this` but you're right, there is a distinction with and w/out `new`, meaning if it's a "real" object or not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects   I have no idea if `as` is supposed to imply `new` or not since that is a "mystery keyword" to me  :)

Comment: I am sorry, I was trying something on jsfiddle, and there they underline `new String("Hallo")` and tell me, that I should NOT use `new` together with `String()`. Probably, the intention is, to not have a new String-Object. https://jsfiddle.net/8hgb0xc5/

Comment: @derM  LOL, I guess it depends on who you ask.  I think [this](https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/literal-constructor.md) is the source of the warning. So basically to protect the programmer from themselves... :)   The "do not" wording is overly Draconian IMHO, especially w/out any explanation (on jsFiddle anyway, had to Google it).